# Find id and IP address of newly created AWS instance using java sdk?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am creating my instances using aws java sdk and my function looks like this

```
private static void createInstance()
            throws AmazonServiceException, AmazonClientException, InterruptedException
    {
     RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest()
            .withInstanceType("m1.small")
            .withImageId("my_ami")
            .withMinCount(1)
            .withMaxCount(1)
            .withKeyName("my_key")
            ;
    RunInstancesResult runInstances = ec2.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);
    }
```

And finding the IP addresses of all the running instances like this:

```
public static ArrayList<String> findIPs(){

         ArrayList<String> myArr = new ArrayList<String>();

         DescribeInstancesResult describeInstancesRequest = ec2.describeInstances();
         List<Reservation> reservations = describeInstancesRequest.getReservations();
         Set<Instance> instances = new HashSet<Instance>();

         for (Reservation reservation : reservations) {
             instances.addAll(reservation.getInstances());
            if(reservation.getInstances().get(0).getPrivateIpAddress()!= null) 
            {


                    myArr.add(reservation.getInstances().get(0).getPrivateIpAddress());


            }


         }
         return myArr;
    }
```

I want to know the instance id and IP address which is being created most recently. Can someone please guide me that how can I find the id and IP address of most recently created AWS instance.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are already 90% of the way there ...

Invoking getInstances() on the Reservation gets you a list of all the instances. And then invoke getLaunchTime() on each instance to get its launch time.

Does this work for you ?